# 1+ month into calisthenics and need guidance

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics

I have made another thread a month ago and I need some new guidance. Here's some info about myself.

Age: 15
Weight: 70kg
Height: 184cm

Pushup PR: 13
Pushup AVG: 6-8
Pullup/Chinup: 0

3/4 times per week

Current workout routine:

50 pushups
50 squats
25 explosive squats
50 bench dips
50 situps
50 crunches
100 short bridges

What should I do next to improve? Should I be doing the same workout? I've been doing this one for a week now but don't see much improvement so I would like some honest opinions and different workout options I could use. If you have anymore questions for me, I'll answer them.

Edit: Goals: 20+ pushups as I've been stuck on 10+ for about 3 weeks now. 1 pullup/chinup and that's about it. Nothing to major as I don't wanna make unrealistic/hard goals.

Edit 3/1/2022: Recently came back to stackoverflow for coding advice and found my old post, so I would like to update you guys. I've tried many different workout routines, but what I do is just the one that I personally like and the one that works for me.

I have hit my goal of 20+ pushups (30 pushups now), and my goal of 1 pullup/chinup (5 pullups / 8 chinups) thanks everyone for the advice and I hope to get even better as time goes on.

Comment: What you should do next is completely dependent on your goals. What do you want to achieve? Edit that into the question.

Comment: @C.Lange Done, sorry.

Comment: How many times per week are you working out? How many sets are you doing to get all those reps with how long of rest between them? 50 pushups with about 13 between each of them is about 4-5 sets, right? Are you in a calorie surplus, are you getting 8-9 hours of sleep?

Comment: @EricWarburton I said in the post I do 3/4 times per week, It depends around 6-8 sets as I do around 5-8 reps per AVG so you can count that yourself, and I take about 2 min rests. Yes I am in a somewhat calorie surplus, I don't have a "good" diet I just eat a lot of protein and healthy food and rarely junk food. I get around 6-7 hours of sleep due to school, sometimes even less... But in summer I was getting 8+.

Comment: I'm betting fixing your sleep schedule will have the biggest impact. We sleep in 90 minute cycles, the first several cycles primarily repair your body from the previous day. The last couple dump hormones into your body that will help promote growth including testosterone and HGH and various others. Since you are young, it is good to get an extra cycle in there. Try to have at minimum 7 hours 45 min from the time you start to go to sleep (15 min to go to sleep), and 9 hours 15 min optimally. I understand that sleeping that much is often difficult, but it is necessary to get optimal results.

Comment: A week is insufficient time to see much improvement. Try elevated or weighted pushups for awhile.

Comment: @EricWarburton I don't think I can do weighted pushup as I don't have anything that I can think of that will put "weight" but I will try elevated pushups for a while and see how that improves, and I'll try to sleep alot more like I used to in the summer thanks for the help guys!

Comment: What about the workout guys? Is it fine or should I add/remove something?

Comment: The major issue with your workout is that you have set numbers. You need to progressively overload. This means, one more rep, one more pound, one harder variation every single workout... or at least attempt to improve every workout. This is why it is so much easier to workout with weights than with your body weight. It is super easy to just add a little bit of weight on each side if you are stuck on a certain number of repetitions. With calisthenics you should try to increase repetitions until they become too easy, then switch to something more difficult that hits the same muscle.

Comment: About weighted pushups: get a backpack (you must have one somewhere) and put anything in it (books, water bottles, sand, anything you have available). Increase the weight every week or when it starts getting easier.

Comment: @EricWarburton Then what workout do you suggest me to do? I don't really understand progressive overload and I don't know good workout routines and as you see I failed to do one myself.

Comment: Your workout is okay, but you need to try to improve each day. That is what progressive overload is. You are progressively increasing (overloading) the difficulty. Say instead of 50 pullups tomorrow, do 51. If the reps start getting too high for your time frame, change pushups to weighted pushups, or decline pushups etc.

Comment: So you are saying I should try adding 5-10 reps to my pushups every 1-2 days or something? And when I reach about 100 pushups I can do it with weights and do the same thing until like 50? If that's a yes then I will, thanks Eric!

Answer (score 1):

We can first try to find out what’s the issue preventing you from hitting 20 reps in a set:

- Is it fatigue in your shoulders, chest or triceps?
- Your hips sagging as you progress into the reps?

Like what others pointed out, give yourself more time and enough rest. I’ll recommend alternating between strength and endurance days.

Mon (strength): Weighted push ups / 4-5 sets of 3-4 repetitions
Wednesday (endurance): Bodyweight push ups / 3-4 sets of 5-6 repetitions
Fri (strength): Same as Monday routine

Repeat for next week. You can try this routine for 4 weeks and see how it goes.

As a general rule, you should stop at the number of reps where you can still go 1-2 more. I will not advocate going to fatigue as of now, and the effects of training to fatigue is debatable. If you find that you can still rep out 3-4 more times with proper form, increase the load or reps for your working set.

*im just focusing on push ups for now.

Comment: My arm/shoulders persay, my chest seems fine but my core is super bad and I don't know  any good core exercises to fix that. And I don't have a way to do weighted pushups execpt for backpack if that's fine.

Comment: Yes backpack is great. In what context do you feel your core is weak? If you can provide images of you doing push ups, I may be able to better help. Generally, if your hips tend to sag, you will want to train your lower abdominals, isometric exercises like plank

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by saying, it's not a bad thing to have goals that might take you a year to achieve, so don't be afraid to set seemingly unrealistic goals.

You can do a couple of things to reach these goals. You can alternate between training for strength (heavier sets with lower reps) and training for endurance (easier sets but more reps).

You can also dissect the movement to find out which part of the movement is holding you back. Do you need to work on your shoulders, triceps, or maybe even core strength or glute strenght?

By doing different variations of the pushup, you can target certain muscles better. i.e. if you want to target triceps more, do pushups with a narrow stance, or even try diamond pushups. All the while you keep your elbows close to your body, not letting them flare out.

Do you need to work on shoulder activation? Perhaps scapula exercises like scapula pushups or scapula dips will help you.

You can apply this advise on every movement there is. Pushups, pullups, muscleups, handstand, front lever, plance, you name it.

I hope that helps.